# Create a prefix for multiple tables in .sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

> We are using React + Node for the projects i talk below :)

I have the below sql tables in one `.sql` file and the problem is all start with the same prefix `sumo_` , is there a way like to create that prefix as a variable or something and append like :

```
prefix+`table_name`
```

[image]

It might seem like trivial , `just search and replace` but actually it's a problem because we want to create a template which automatically replaces prefixes because we have hundreds of projects with that problem.

For example in javascript you can do :

```
const prefix = "sumo_"
const tableName = prefix+"lalalal"
```

Current file exanple :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sumo_application_elements` (
  `id`                 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_element_id`  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description`        varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `url`                text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `resource_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_class` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_key` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `script_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `addnew_url` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `element_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sumo_languages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `culture` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sumo_languages_un` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sumo_resources` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `language_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `translation_text` varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sumo_resources_sumo_languages_fk` (`language_code`),
  UNIQUE (code, language_code),
  CONSTRAINT `sumo_resources_sumo_languages_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`language_code`) REFERENCES `sumo_languages` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sumo_lookups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `resource_key` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sumo_lookups_un` (`code`, `key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sumo_app_elm_rl` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `rl_key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `sel_perm` smallint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `upd_perm` smallint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`rl_key`),
  CONSTRAINT `sumo_elm_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `sumo_application_elements` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: This may be solved using dynamic SQL ([prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)) only.

Comment: Use Hibernate custom NamingStrategy (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html). Example can be found here : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/

Comment: @KumarAshutosh I am using it in a React+Node Project , i will edit the question :) , thank you i will keep that in mind for Java Projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i finally did ?

[image]

I replaced wherever is the prefix for example `sumo` with `#prefix#` so in the **create-schema.js**:

```
/* Where #prefix# is the table name prefix of the application*/


/* Holds the menu elements (Ex. simple menu items or menu items with childs ) */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#prefix#_application_elements` (
  `id`                      int(11)                              NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_element_id`       int(11)                      DEFAULT NULL,
  `description`             varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `url`                     text        COLLATE utf8_bin             ,
  `resource_id`             varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_number`            int(11)                      DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_class`              varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_key`                 varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `script_name`             varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `addnew_url`              text        COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `element_type_id`         int(11)                              NOT NULL COMMENT '1 = App,  2 = ParentApp, 3 = ChildApp',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

/* Holds the langauges supported by the application */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#prefix#_languages` (
  `id`                      int(11)                              NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code`                    varchar(45)                          NOT NULL,
  `name`                    varchar(45)                          NOT NULL,
  `display_name`            varchar(60)                  DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_enabled`              tinyint(1)                           NOT NULL,
  `culture`                 varchar(45)                  DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency`                varchar(100)                 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `#prefix#_languages_un` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

....etc more and more tables here with the prefix
```

Then on the migration file **1-schema.js** :

```
const replaceTablePrefix = require('../tools/tools.js')

exports.up = (knex, Promise) => {
   const initialSchemaScript = replaceTablePrefix('schema-create')

   return knex.raw(initialSchemaScript)
}

exports.down = (knex, Promise) => {
   const dropSchemaScript = replaceTablePrefix('schema-drop')

   return knex.raw(dropSchemaScript)
}
```

So here it is **tool.js** :

```
const Fs = require('fs')
const Path = require('path')
const tableName = 'sumo'

const replaceTablePrefix = fileName => {
   const fileContent = Fs.readFileSync(Path.join(__dirname, `../db/${fileName}.sql`), 'utf8').replace(/#prefix#/g, tableName)
   return fileContent
}

module.exports = replaceTablePrefix
```